# Disable hyperlink if cell value null in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a grid where columns are populated dynamically. I have a column called ID which will have hyperlink enabled and hyperlinks needs to be disabled if cells value is null or empty.

**For ex:**
If a cell value returns `0` or null values for that ID column then I need to disable the hyperlink for those cells in that columns. The below code adds hyperlink successfully and top of it I need to check for `null` or `0` values in the cell.

**Code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            string strHeaderRow = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
            if (strHeaderRow == "ID")
            {
                string strMktURL = "http://www.address.com";
                HyperLink hlColumns = AddHyperLink(e.Row.Cells[i], strMktURL);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected HyperLink AddHyperLink(TableCell cell, string strURL)
{
    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
    hl.Text = cell.Text;
    hl.Font.Underline = true;
    hl.Target = "_blank";
    hl.NavigateUrl = strURL;
    hl.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Black;");
    cell.Controls.Add(hl);
    return hl;
}
```

Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Comment: What does your code not do that you want it to? What does it do now? It's not clear what you're asking and what exactly you want to achieve (e.g. 'disable' the hyperlink or just not put a hyperlink into that cell if the value is blank/null?). Please edit question to be more clear.

Comment: @Rory - Updated my post. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for your cell value is `null` or empty and **don't** make it hyperlink.
Also I will suggest to make your `AddHyperLink()` void, if you will not use its returned value.

### UPDATE

[`TableCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) stores its value into `string Text` property, so:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string strMktURL = "http://www.address.com";
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            string strHeaderRow = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
            if (strHeaderRow == "ID")
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text))
                {
                    HyperLink hlColumns = AddHyperLink(e.Row.Cells[i], strMktURL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work and I think its about formatting. FYI if its a integer or decimal how can I handle that?

Comment: So `integer` or `decimal`?

Comment: If its `int` or `decimal`, it can't be empty, only `null` if its `Nullable`.

Comment: Its an int. I am getting error in this line `(e.Row.Cells[i] as int?)` Cannot convert type TableCell to int? via a reference conversion.

Comment: Ok, I don't have any experiences with Gridview, but according to MSDN, TableCell stores its value into `string Text` property, so look at Updated answer.

Comment: I can still see the hyperlink enabled for cells with null values.

Comment: @vicky maybe check for `!= "null"`, it is more likely issue with your data binding, just don't assign `null` values or make them empty strings. I'm just showing the way, how can you achieve that.